# ADFS ignores my claim request

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, claims-based-identity, ws-federation, federation

I get ADFS details of user via wsfed, via:
https://github.com/auth0/passport-wsfed-saml2

and I only get nameID.

metadata.xml (my server address was replaced with http://localhost/app/, it is ran in https):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EntityDescriptor ID="_5b6cd05c-a5e3-470d-a2fc-6c6f66633d1b" entityID="http://localhost/app/" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <RoleDescriptor xsi:type="fed:ApplicationServiceType" xmlns:fed="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706" protocolSupportEnumeration="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <fed:ClaimTypesRequested>
            <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" Optional="true" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" />
            <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" Optional="true" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" />
        </fed:ClaimTypesRequested>
        <fed:TargetScopes>
            <EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                <Address>http://localhost/app/</Address>
            </EndpointReference>
        </fed:TargetScopes>
        <fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
            <EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                <Address>http://localhost/app/</Address>
            </EndpointReference>
        </fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
    </RoleDescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

even whenever I replace "optional" to false it doesn't return any claims.
does anyone why ADFS ignores my claims?

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting ADFS to derive the claims from "ClaimTypesRequested"?

The way ADFS works is that the claims are derived from claims rules that are configured in ADFS.

What claims rules have you got configured?

Comment: I expect that the specific claims I mentioned will be returned to the callback. If I mention "role" I expect to get the role property in the response. Can't I specify which data I want back from the ADFS?

Comment: You can but the determining factor is the claims rules configured on ADFS. No claims rules - no claims.